# How to declare field of type that extends some class?

Tags: typescript

Consider following:

```
class Base{
}

class A extends Base{
}

class B {
}
```

now I want to have implementation (type) of `Base` wrapped into object

```
interface MyImpl{
   name:string;
   impl:any;
}
```

How to delcare `impl` instead of `any` so that following `{name:"Aname", impl: A}` will be valid while `{name:"Bname",impl:B}` will be invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface MyImpl {
   name: string;
   impl: typeof Base;
}
```

This way, `Base` and any class that extends it will be assignable to `impl`.

Comment: Nah, this would accept INSTANCES of `Base` while I want to have type here. In Java I would do `Class<? extends Base> impl`

Comment: Maybe you want to make `Base` into an abstract class. That way it can't be instantiated anywhere without being extended first.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that you want to assign the class itself, not an instance. In that case what you want is `typeof Base`.

Comment: But at the end, what I really needed was `impl: new() => Base;` as I wanted to create instance of given class.